# Putting `QuantitativeValue` from schema.org into `td` element

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I have following piece of code as part of my `Product`:

```
<tr>
   <th>Width:</th>
   <td itemprop="width" href="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
      <?php echo $product->width."mm"; ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately it generates following error:

> Attribute `href` not allowed on element `td` at this point.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`width` property](http://schema.org/width) expects an item ([`Distance`](http://schema.org/Distance) or [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue)) as value.

So you need something like this:

```
<td itemprop="width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
</td>
```

Comment: See also my answer with [more examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23113088/1591669).