# Product size: width, height and depth

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I'm using schema.org definition to represent a product.
I have a doubt about product size: should I specify the unit of measure in the field?

Here's my code (I need a separate `span` for "cm" to style it differently):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Product name</h1>

    Size: 
    <span itemprop="width">60 <span>cm</span></span>
    <span itemprop="height">50 <span>cm</span></span>
    <span itemprop="depth">40 <span>cm</span></span>
</div>
```

Is this the correct way to define the size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`width`](http://schema.org/width)/[`depth`](http://schema.org/depth)/[`height`](http://schema.org/height) properties expect [`Distance`](http://schema.org/Distance) or [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) as value.

#### If you want to use `Distance`:

As the `Distance` type does not seem to define a suitable property to provide the actual value, and its description says that values have

> […] the form '<Number> <Length unit of measure>'. E.g., '7 ft'.

I assume that the type should not be provided explicitly, e.g.:

```
<span itemprop="width">
  60 <span>cm</span>
</span>
```

If the type should be provided, I guess using `name` is the only option:

```
<span itemprop="width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Distance">
  <span itemprop="name">60 <span>cm</span></span>
</span>
```

#### If you want to use `QuantitativeValue`:

```
<span itemprop="width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
  <span itemprop="value">60</span>
  <span>cm</span>
  <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="CMT" />
</span>
```

Instead of specifying the UN/CEFACT code for "cm" (= `CMT`) in a `meta` element (which is [allowed in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633), if you use it for Microdata), you could also use the `data` element:

```
<span itemprop="width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
  <span itemprop="value">60</span>
  <data itemprop="unitCode" value="CMT">cm</data>
</span>
```

Comment: What is a `data` element? Given the OP, is seems like that should be a `span`?

Comment: @DanFriedman: [`data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element) is an HTML5 element. I explained in my answer why `span`+`data` or `span`+`meta` should be used for [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue). Could you clarify what exactly is unclear?

Comment: @unor Thanks for the good example. The HTML of Distance is smaller and easier to create, so is there any benefit of using QuantitativeValue? Does all search engines treat 'Distance' and 'QuantitativeValue' similarly?

Comment: Hi @unor or other reader - any knowledge of how to accomplish similar using JSON LD markup? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754758/how-to-specify-product-dimensions-or-weight-including-unit-of-measure-in-schem thanks! =)